# Stereo AM/FM Concept?

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf

There are tons of schematics and concepts online of AM or FM transmitters. I wish to build one using discrete components (at most an op-amp).

The problem is, how would transmission of stereo work? In my current circuit, I have two outputs from pre-amps for left and right channel. I want this to be transmitted and played back on a radio correctly.

Is this just a matter of transmitting left and right separately on two op-amps but on the same frequency? Would that work? Or would the signals likely cancel each other out?

Comment: OK, so you've seen the tons of schematics on-line for transmitters and presumably one or two have "suggested" that they can be built using op-amps. Would you, as courtesy to anyone answering please give a link to what you feel may be the most appropriate starting point?

Comment: Have you done basic research? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting#Stereo_FM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM_stereo

Answer (score 6):

As Olin says, stereo FM is quite a complex project for someone just starting out with electronics.
Mono FM transmits an L+R signal in the first 15kHz of it's bandwidth. For the stereo, it involves transmitting a L-R signal above this (mono receivers only look at the first 15kHz) and then recovering each channel by (L+R) + (L-R) = 2L, and (L+R) - (L-R) = 2R.
There is also a pilot tone to indicate the stereo channel and some other stuff involved. [This link](http://transmitters.tripod.com/stereo.htm) will give you an idea of what you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry, but there is simply no way to explain this at your level.  You can probably look around on the net and get a mono AM or even FM transmitter working.  Please remember to keep the power low, because simple transmitter circuits you will find on the web will cause radio interference beyond just transmitting on the desired channel.  Technically this is illegal, but if you keep the power low and use a empty channel you hopefully won't bother anyone else to the point they complain.

To try to answer your question somewhat, AM is mono only.  FM does stereo by broadcasting the left+right signal in the "normal" way, then hiding a left-right signal someplace a plain old FM receiver won't notice.  Actually today you probably can't even find a FM receiver that doesn't also decode the left-right channel and then does the linear transformations to produce the separeate left and right signals.  However, making a transmitter that does all that is not a beginner project, and I don't know how to explain it without getting into frequency spectrums, frequency shifting, and the like.  Stick to mono.

Answer (score 3):

The main audio signal in FM is limited in bandwidth to 15 Khz and is mono. A simple receiver will decode the mono and that is it. If the station is stereo, then the mono represents is the mix of the left and right channels: L+R.

Even though the audio material is limited to 15 Khz, there is space left over in the frequency band to encode additional information.

There is a "station within a station" essentially. Prior to FM encoding, an AM signal is added, whose carrier is 38 Khz. This is called a subcarrier: a carrier within the signal itself.

This 38 Khz subcarrier is modulated with the stereo difference between left and right, L-R.

A stereo FM decoder will take the additional step of taking the decoded signal from the FM station, which contains the mono audio as well as the subcarrier, and then decoding the 38 Khz AM signal to obtain the difference signal, which is then combined with the mono to reproduce the right channel. \$(L+R) + (L-R) = 2L\$ and \$(L+R) - (L-R) = 2R\$.

Note that since the 38 Khz subcarrier is modulated with a signal covering 15 Khz of audio bandwidth, it will have side bands extending from 38 - 15 = 23 Khz to  38 + 15 + 53 Khz. This leaves a generous buffer space between lower limit of 23 Khz and the mono audio which goes up to 15 Khz and 23 Khz.  Inside this space, a 19Khz pilot tone is played by an FM stereo station which indicates "stereo is available".   If the pilot tone is missing, it advises receivers not to try to decode the stereo information.

A stereo transmitter does not actually have to perform fastidious AM modulation to generate the stereo signal. That requires a nice, sinusoidal oscillator, and a voltage-controlled amplifier driven by a difference amplifier.  Instead, there is a "cheat" method for generating the modulated left-right difference signal. A chopper circuit driven by a 38 Khz square wave takes both of the audio channels as inputs, and rapidly toggles between them. When the square wave is high, it passes through (essentially samples) one channel, and when the square wave is low, it passes the other channel. (This is very much like the chopping done by a dual trace analog scope to make two traces appear on the tube.)  The chopping will generate L+R and L-R signals, relative to the 38 Khz chopping frequency. The chopped signal has to be subject to some filtering to remove harmonics and it's good to go.

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect.  The mono channel actually contains left+right.  The second channel is left-right.  From a linear combination of these, the receiver recovers individual left and right.  The main advantage of this scheme is that mono is what you expect, which is both channels.

Comment: The pilot does more than just 'advise'. It is derived from, and substitutes for, the 38kHz subcarrier, which is suppressed for bandwidth reasons. The tuner syncs to the pilot to reconstitute the missing subcarrier. Without the pilot it is not just inadvisable but completely impossible to decode into stereo. The 'cheat' isn't really cheating, it is a mathematically equivalent way of accomplishing the same thing, and it's a lot simpler. At the tuner the decoder just reconstitutes a 38kHz switching tone and switches with it, producing L and R directly, and then de-emphasis and filter.